# Which of these method layout is better practice?

Tags: methods, coding-style

I have 2 styles:

```
public void methodA() {
     // do something
}

public void methodB()
{
     // do something
}
```

Which is better in practice?

Comment: Questions about coding style are inherently subjective, and therefore not suitable for Stack Overflow...

Comment: Both are used by numerous programmers. With their reasons. So we won't resolve this question here in a constructive way. Look at what's used by good coders in your language around you.

Comment: Note also that this isn't language independent : some of them impose a bracing style (e.g. Go).

Comment: The one that the rest of the team (or the rest of the code) uses is the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use whatever standards the rest of your team have set out.

Never get into a debate over which is *better* unless productivity is not a priority.

Comment: Somebody else found before you this was better as a comment.

Comment: Hi dystroy - thanks for the constructive advice.  If you have a link to a page which denotes "what should be what", I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to chose from.

1. Use whatever your team is using. Reason behind this is consistency across the team.
2. If you don't have any coding standard in your team regarding this then use the standard that your IDE does by default. The reason behind this is that most people use IDEs default and it increases consistency with other programmers winin out outside your team. Another reason is that any new team member does not have to change the formatting rule in the IDE and can use auto format without accidently messing up with the previous format. This is true when you are the only developer in the team.
3. If your IDE does not auto format then check other programs in the same language from github or other source repository and follow that rule for your team or yourself. Again the reason is consistency.